# How can I use '*' to capture everything with exceptions

Tags: bash, wildcards

For example, I have files named

```
A_1.txt A_t_1.txt A_ts_1.txt A_tsa_1.txt
```

in a directory `~/admin/packages/`.

I am building a for loop to by globbing to A_1.txt

```
for f in ~/admin/packages/*_1.txt
```

It's obvious that this can potentially glob to any one of these files.

Specifically I would like to use an "exception" command (if it exists) to say glob to any file as long as it does not have a `t`, `s`, `a` before `_1.txt`.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have the path stored as a variable.

```
PROJECT="~/admin/packages/*_1.txt"

for f in ${PROJECT}...
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using the following `extglob` pattern in `bash`:

```
!(*t|*s|*a)_1.txt
```

Enable `extglob` at first (if not enabled) by:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then you can do:

```
for f in ~/admin/packages/!(*t|*s|*a)_1.txt; do ##Something; done
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo *_1.txt
A_1.txt Ab_1.txt A_t_1.txt A_ts_1.txt A_tsa_1.txt

$ shopt -s extglob

$ echo !(*t|*s|*a)_1.txt
A_1.txt Ab_1.txt
```

---

Shortened (thanks to [chaos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52727/chaos)):

```
!(*[tsa])_1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

You could set your `PROJECT` var to `~/admin/packages/*[^tsa]_1.txt`

```
PROJECT="~/admin/packages/*[^tsa]_1.txt"
```

If you can modify it.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `case` statement to weed out the exceptions, like this:

```
for f in ${PROJECT}; do
    case "$f" in *[tsa]_1*) continue;; esac

    # ... actual work here ...
done
```

Answer (score 1):

(in bash) The exact answer to your request is to use `GLOBIGNORE`:

By executing this command:

```
LESS=+/'^ *GLOBIGNORE' man bash
```

read:

> GLOBIGNORE
>   A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.

So, by setting `GLOBIGNORE` like this:

```
$  ls *
A_1.txt  A_t_1.txt  A_ts_1.txt  A_tsa_1.txt
$ GLOBIGNORE=*t_1.txt:*s_1.txt:*a_1.txt
$ ls *
A_1.txt
```

After that you may restore `GLOBIGNORE` to empty with `unset GLOBIGNORE`.